# I've got a new iPod Touch, do I need a new Apple ID for FaceTime and iMessage

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, ipod-touch

We have a Mac, iPad2, 1 iPhone 4, 1 iPhone 4s and now have bought an iPod Touch for my son.

What is the best way for the iPod Touch to be able to sync previuosly download apps and music but enable Facetime and iMessage using his own details as my wife's details are used for her FaceTime/Apple ID?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could’ve waited a week or two and bought your son the fifth generation iPod touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, you can set different IDs for Communications (FaceTime, iMessage, etc) and Stores (iTunes, App Store, iBooks Store). Let’s say `one@me.com` is your wife’s ID, and your son **has already created** `two@me.com` for his own use. The steps would be:

1. Go to Settings > iTunes and App Stores. Sign in with `one@me.com`.
2. Go to Settings > FaceTime and sign in with `two@me.com`.
3. Go to Settings > Messages and sign in with `two@me.com`.

Source: http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/ios.html